# Prevent pdf file's content from modifying

Tags: permissions, security, pdf

How can I create a read-only pdf file in Ubuntu?

Comment: You want to make it unmodifiable or uncopyable?

Comment: Read-only and not copyable are not the same. To copy a file or a document's content, it has to be readable. Read-only means it may not be modified. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Assuming you don't want the recipient to copy chunks of text, one way may be to scan the document after introducing some "background noise" so that recipients will have a hard time training their OCR to retrieve text. Then make a pdf of that scanned image.

Comment: Yes, I meant to make it unmodifiable, edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he means preventing content from copying it. There is no way to prevent that. If you can read it, then you can copy it. The only way how to make it harder is convert all pages to pictures. Then you can read it, but you will not be able to plain copy the text without some OCR.

Comment: I think Youre right @Gordon . There is no way to prevent copying a pdf in any system. Windows, Mac, Linux. For every-method that exists to prevent copying, there is a method to break it.  I have had jobs trying to secure online ebooks. A method I prefer is to embed the name of persons, and or an ID of whomever bought the ebook.  later, when I find a copy on a torrent site, I look at the embedded info and see who has been sharing their book. That's not a fool proof solution, it relies on persons who share the ebooks to not clean the embedded info out before sharing.